# Solr still showing indexed items after clearning

Tags: search, 9

I have a solr install that is hooked up and running. After clearing the index I am still getting search results to show up and the solr server is saying that there are still 19363 items indexed when viewing the server. But when viewing the index it says there are 0/19363 items.

When I try to reindex, Drupal goes through the long process of reindexing but my changes to fields and field processors seem to not apply, in particular trying to not index unpublished nodes. The index will now say 19363/19363 items indexed.

I have rebuilt tracking, reindexed, cleared caches and everything else I can think of but my server is still showing search results after I have tried deleting everything. I can even go into the solr admin and run a query there and I can see results as well.

I am using solr 8.11.1 and Drupal 9.

I could try to delete my core and start over... but I feel like that could be bypassing a larger issue that could rear its head later.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Drupal modules are you using to integrate with Solr? What are their versions?

Comment: Search API Solr 4.2.7 :  Search API v8.x-1.23 : Facets v2.0.2 : Facets Searchbox Widget 2.0.2 : Facets SUmmary v2.0.2 : Better Exposed Filters v8.x-5.1 : Views Block Exposed Filter Block v 8.x.1-2 : Facets Block v8.x-1.04